# How can I include or link a css file in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm still new to ReactJS and I'm looking for a way to link css file in the `.jsx` file. I'm aware of inline styles but the styles I want to include are just much too long to put in a single react file.

I have a react component like this:

```
var Button = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <a href="#" class="button circled scrolly">Take Off</a>
        );
    }
});
```

Where `class`, `button` and `scrolly` are all in the css file. How can I include the css file to make it render the styles as well?

EDIT:

Changed `class` to `className` and it is working fine now

Comment: it's `className` in jsx, not `class`... and without getting fancy why not just include the css file in your `index.html` file like 'normal'?

Comment: It is in my `index.html` but it's not rendering the styles, so I assumed I needed a workaround for it to work with reactjs